What is the range of bandwidths between datacenters?
I am trying to estimate the typical bandwidth between data centres, especially in the context of high-load applications such as AI training.
My current approach is as follows:

Modern transceivers seem capable of 400 Gbps connections (per channel?)
Dense Wavelength Division Multiplexing (DWDM) systems can carry between 40 and 160 channels
I could not find any information on the typical number of links between datacenters, but I see no fundamental reason why you could not have 10-100 links.

With these assumptions, I would arrive at a bandwidth of 400 Gbps x 80 channels x 100 links = 3,200 Tbps.
What gives me pause here is that the MAREA trans-Atlantic cable has a total system capacity of 200 Tbps, which is 16 times lower than my estimate — and I would have naively expected that the typical inter-datacenter bandwidth would be lower.
Is my BOTEC very off? If so, why?

One source (https://blog.telegeography.com/total-international-bandwidth-now-stands-at-1217-tbps)  says "Total international internet bandwidth now stands at 1,217 Tbps,". Another in 2021 900T (https://www.itu.int/itu-d/reports/statistics/2021/11/15/international-bandwidth-usage/). So I'd guess your estimate is a bit hight. Wouldn't this be better at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

@Mat thanks! Good suggestion, I Xposted it there

I'm not a member of the Network Engineering Stack Exchange, but their tour says Don't ask about A network under someone else's control, so not sure if this question will be well received.

@Jsevillamol You're jumbling up channels, lanes and links, and are completely ignoring reach limits. "100 links" means 200 fiber strands - seriously?

@Zac67, The link OP shared was for a 800G ZR module, capable of (according to the press release) 450 km reach. And 200 strands isn't outrageous for a WAN-scale cable. Strands are cheap. Digging new trenches is expensive.

OP, what you're suggesting appears to be physically possible. The question is whether there's a compelling reason to invest in connecting data centers so densely, as opposed to, for example, building larger individual data centers, or designing the computations done not to require such dense interconnection.

I don't think there is a "typical" bandwidth for a data center anymore than there is a typical power consumption for a factory or a typical road capacity for a mine. The type and number of links is going to be determined by the operator, who can install as many as they need but won't install more than they want to pay for.

@Zac67 can you explain to me the difference between channels, lanes and links?

Why would you expect a cable thousands of miles long under miles of ocean to be a good benchmark for what's possible between data centers that might be just tens of miles apart on land?
